# В IDEA в Maven проектах не отображается документация

Tags: intellij-idea, maven, документация, javadoc

У IDEA, как и многих других сред программирования, есть замечательная функция (включается опционально), которая отображает документацию при наведении курсора на класс, метод интерфейс или т.д.

[image: Пример окошка функции]

Но есть одна проблема, которая уже очень давно меня беспокоила, но никак не мог найти решение, а теперь решил задать вопрос здесь. В Maven управляемых проектах документация не отображается, чтобы я не делал. Отображается лишь подобное пустое окошко:

[image: Пустое окно]

Может быть, кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой и знает решение? Покопавшись в настройках Maven выставил галочку "Загружать документацию", но это никак не повлияло. При этом внутри самих классов документация есть.

Comment: А по `Ctrl+Q` тоже не отображается? У меня есть maven-проекты и в них всё прекрасно отображается. Правда, по `Ctrl+Q`, по наведении мыши я не включал.

Comment: @kff `Ctrl+Q` это тоже самое, просто я предпочитаю наводить курсор. И нет, не отображается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл ответ, оказалось, что это проблема самой IDEA в некоторых версиях, нужно было просто обновить программу.